# 入力画面のエラーチェックについて。

Tags: php

下記のようなサイトで入力画面で入力した値についてformのaction属性で確認画面に飛ばしてエラーチェックをせず自画面(単一ページ)でエラーチェックをしています。確認画面に遷移させてエラーチェックをせず単一ページでエラーチェックをしている理由は単一ページだけで入力データのエラーチェックを完結でき、確認画面のファイルを読み込まなくてすむので処理の負担が軽くなるからなのでしょうか。
http://www.aso.ne.jp/~kira/php/check.php
http://klutche.org/archives/989/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

パフォーマンスよりもユーザビリティ視点での実装じゃないかなと個人的には思います。

入力必須の項目が未入力だったとして、エラー画面を表示して「前のページに戻ってください」とするより、未入力があることを伝えつつ実際の入力画面を表示してくれた方が親切です。
そして入力画面は既にあるわけですから、エラーチェックのスクリプトとして別個に用意して同じフォームを二重管理するより、単一ページで呼び出してしまった方がコーディングも楽です。